# Host Access to VirtualBox VMs Configuration Issue

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I'm trying to configure three VMs on Virtualbox so that I can access them from the host machine. I've configured two NICs, one as NAT and the other for host-only adaptor, and booting Centos 7. My host-only adaptor is set to configure manually with ip of 192.168.56.1 with mask 24. When I try to ping them, I get following error message:

> Destination Host Unavailable

Would anyone be able to help me here?

I tried to configure the interfaces from the Centos anaconda UI as static, manually configured IPs, as well as automatic DHCP. When I provision manually, I see the IP via nmcli device show, but can only ping the gateway IP.

Comment: Thanks @John. This was very helpful and allowed me to get things running.